# Reading column-wise data from a text file in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, cplex

I am using Eclipse in concert with CPLEX to model a vehicle routing problem. I need to read data(demand point coordinates, time windows, etc) from a text file. The data is column-wise, and so I used a split function to store in it my variables. However the console shows an error on the first line of data itself.

Code:

```
public class VRP01k {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException{

    //Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("C:\\OR Research\\Code\\data01.txt"));
    Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("data01.txt"));

String line = input.nextLine();
      while(line != null) {
          String[] columns = line.split("\t");
          xPos[count] = Double.parseDouble(columns[0]);
          yPos[count] = Double.parseDouble(columns[1]);
          d[count] = Double.parseDouble(columns[2]);
          a[count] = Double.parseDouble(columns[3]);
          b[count] = Double.parseDouble(columns[4]);
          s[count] = Double.parseDouble(columns[5]);

          count++;
          line = input.nextLine();
    }
```

I tried using the file from the C drive directly and by moving it into my Java Project. Neither works. The error is as follows:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "3.00      38.00       0.00       0.00    1187.00       0.00"
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2043)
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538)
    at VRP01k.main(VRP01k.java:32)
```

The first few rows of the data file are:

```
 3.00      38.00       0.00       0.00    1187.00       0.00
44.00      28.00       0.00     342.00     365.00       0.00
26.00      44.00       0.00      20.00      93.00       0.00
 7.00      41.00       0.00       0.00      45.00       0.00
17.00      28.00       0.00     250.00     292.00       0.00
```

Please help. Thanks.

Here's the new code:

```
public class VRP01k {
public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException{

//Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("C:\\OR Research\\Code\\data01.txt"));
Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("data01.txt"));
    String line = input.nextLine();
         while(line != null) {
              String [] columns = line.trim().split("\\s+");
              xPos[count] = Double.parseDouble(columns[0]);
              yPos[count] = Double.parseDouble(columns[1]);
              d[count] = Double.parseDouble(columns[2]);
              a[count] = Double.parseDouble(columns[3]);
              b[count] = Double.parseDouble(columns[4]);
              s[count] = Double.parseDouble(columns[5]);

              count++;
              line = input.nextLine();
                }
```

And the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1842)
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538)
    at VRP01k.main(VRP01k.java:32)
```

Comment: Your split isn't working - probably you don't actually have tab characters between the numbers.

Comment: Try trimming, ex `columns[0].trim()`. And try printing out `columns[0]` to whether the split really happened.

Comment: probably they are just spaces.. check that...

Comment: @greg-449 It seems there weren't any tab characters after all. But how do I then differentiate b/w different elements of each row? the spaces b/w the numbers is varying.

Comment: See my answer which deals with variable numbers of spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your exception says there is an error in the format of the number for the input:

```
"3.00      38.00       0.00       0.00    1187.00       0.00"
```

so your `split` is not actually splitting up the input string and is just passing the whole line to the first `Double.parseDouble`.

Most likely you have blanks rather than tabs between the numbers. So use something like:

```
String [] columns = line.trim().split("\\s+");
```

for the split. This is trimming leading and trailing spaces before doing the split to make things easier and is then splitting on one or more 'space' characters - this will deal with blanks and tabs.

Comment: I tried this, but it shows an error regarding an empty string.  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String.

Comment: It works for me on your first line of data. What line is causing a problem?

Comment: The console doesn't mention that. If I use six whitespace characters as a delimiter it goes up to 0.00   1187.00 and then fails, but using \\s+ is giving an empty string

Comment: Show us exactly what code you are now using and exactly what the problem input line is.

Comment: I included the new code and error in the question itself.